# Why does an Ant Exec task return code not match ERRORLEVEL value?

Tags: java, ant, batch-file

I have a batch script called from Ant exec task to compile some CSharp code. The batch script is structured in the following way

```
msbuild.exe %ARGS%
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Now when the task is run in Ant, I get the following result:

```
 [exec] Time Elapsed 00:00:09.48
 [exec] 0

 BUILD FAILED
 C:\proj\build.xml:410: exec returned: 2
```

How is it possible that %ERRORLEVEL% is 0, but the Ant exec gets a return code of 2? Is this some default error code set if the command does not return a code? Ant docs show:

```
error code 2 means 'no such program',
```

But clearly my batch file is being executed correctly.

**Update with Ant Code**

```
<target name="build.csharp" if="isWindowsPlatform">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe" failOnError="true">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="build.csharp.bat" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Could you post some or all of your build.xml file?  I had a similar problem, where I was attempting to start exe's using properties like <property name="Notepad++.Dir" value="C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/" />, but then I just put the full path directly into the exec command, and it opened the exe for me no problem!

Answer (score 2):

The [ANT manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) states:

> ## Errors and return codes
>
> By default the return code of a `<exec>` is ignored; when you set `failonerror="true"` then any return code signaling failure (OS specific) causes the build to fail. Alternatively, you can set `resultproperty` to the name of a property and have it assigned to the result code (barring immutability, of course).
>
> If the attempt to start the program fails with an OS dependent error code, then `<exec>` halts the build unless `failifexecutionfails` is set to `false`. You can use that to run a program if it exists, but otherwise do nothing.
>
> What do those error codes mean? Well, they are OS dependent. On Windows boxes you have to look at the documentation; error code 2 means 'no such program', which usually means it is not on the path. Any time you see such an error from any Ant task, it is usually not an Ant bug, but some configuration problem on your machine.

To obtain the program's return code you need to use the **resultproperty** attribute of the [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to get the error level. I just want Ant to behave correctly, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: @Casey Post the build.xml fragment you're executing and perhaps someone can help. ANT may very well be behaving correctly :-)

Answer (score 1):

I ran a bunch of permutations. I tried:

- no final exit statement, just the command
- `exit %errorlevel%`
- `exit /b %errorlevel%`
- `@comspec /c exit %errorlevel%`

The only technique that would allow ant to see the correct error code was `exit %errorlevel%`. While the script works correctly now, it is slightly annoying since running it directly from a command shell will cause the shell to exit afterwards. (Invoking the script via `cmd /c` works, but is cumbersome.)

I'd love to here from a DOS expert that can explain these results and expand on them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article in the ANT wiki on this behavior including a solution:
http://wiki.apache.org/ant/AntOnWindows